# How to write a custom web form in Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: customization, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a requirement of a custom grid in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013. From a SharePoint perspective, it would have been a web part. But in CRM 2013, I don't see a similar concept. I need the custom grid to be displayed in a pane for an Entity in CRM? How could that be implemented if possible? Any ideas?

Comment: I think your question is too broad. Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), modify it accordingly and try to narrow it down

Comment: yes I realized that. The answer on my post has helped me clarify this. So I'm not modifying the original question for now. Is that okay?

Comment: You should make your question as clear as possible from the beginning. A good clearly defined question will get upvotes, draw high quality answers that will probably help you a lot and it will help future readers who are having the same problem.

Comment: i´ve just found this tutorial looking for kind of the same answer, is about creating a Silverlight App and embedding it in the form as an iFRAME, hope it helps:


http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2011/06/23/how-to-create-a-silverlight-web-resource-that-interacts-with-crm-2011-forms.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is to broad, but i think what you mean is how to make a custom web page in CRM.

In Dynamics CRM 2013, you cannot add a custom aspx page, as part of a CRM,
you can only put custom Silverlight and HTML/Javascript powered web pages, the latter being the preferred way, of creating these.

However if you need to create a custom web application, you can create it as a separate web application in a separate IIS website, use the CRM web services to access data, and then embed this web application in an iframe on an entity form in CRM.

In order to connect to the crm web service, from custom apps you can use early or late binding.

1. Early binding sample [code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334754.aspx)
2. Late binding sample [code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328416.aspx)

Personally i use late binding as connection is easier and it seems to have better performance. The simplest way to obtain a connection to the CRM service for CRUD operations is the following code:

```
string connString = "Url={DynamicsCRMUrl}; Username=username; Password=password; DeviceID=AnyDeviceId; DevicePassword=AnyDevicePasscode";
CrmConnection crm = CrmConnection.Parse(connString);
IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService)new OrganizationService(crm);
```

For crm online and IFD configured CRM you must add the DeviceID and DevicePassword, for on premise it is not necessary.

Make sure you have the [CRM 2013 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40321) for the required assemblies.

I am answering the question with a long shot, with assumptions, as i am not sure if this is what you require, but i hope it gives you guidance.

Comment: Thanks Bojan, I need to write a custom web app, I don't think Silverlight is a way to go given that it's being discontinued already. Could you please clarify a bit, how the authentication works in this scenario? We also have SSL setup as well. Any helpful links on that.

Comment: I have edited the answer with sample codes and links on how to obtain connection to the CRM web services, in order to perform CRUD operations.

Comment: Defining better performance is not a part of this question, I am simply stating my opinion and personal experience.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an HTML WebResource in CRM that contains the grid to be displayed.

Depending on what you want to display on the grid, the data could be populated using the Dynamics CRM SDK REST API. (see SDK.REST.js).

Once you have set-up your HTML web resource, you can then include it in your entity form as an iframe component (similar to a SharePoint web part).

This approach means you don't need to host the grid in a separate website, but can include it as part of your CRM solution.